# Invalid column name error when using a String.Format object as query parameter for SqlCommand

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a method that only works as below (using cmd.Parameters.Add()):

```
public int insert_customer(
    String _firstname,
    String _middlename,
    String _lastname,
    String _address,
    String _address2,
    String _city,
    String _state,
    String _zipcode)
{
    int rows;

    String query = "INSERT INTO EmployeeInformation (firstname, middlename, lastname, address, address2, city, state, zipcode) values (@_firstname, @_middlename, @_lastname, @_address, @_address2, @_city, @_state, @_zipcode);";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionstring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _firstname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_middlename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _middlename;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _lastname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _address;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_address2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _address2;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_city", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _city;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_state", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _state;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@_zipcode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _zipcode;            

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return rows;
}
```

But when I only use a String.Format() object as below to insert the values from the insert_customer method I receive an error. The error is below, where 'xxx' are the values from my text boxes.

> Invalid column name 'xxx'.\r\nInvalid column name 'xxx'.\r\nInvalid column name 'xxx'.\r\nInvalid column name 'xxx'.\r\nInvalid column name 'xxx'.\r\nInvalid column name 'xxx'.\r\nInvalid column name 'xxx'.\r\nInvalid column name 'xxx'.

Does anyone know why the first method works but the method below does not?

```
public int insert_customer(
    String _firstname,
    String _middlename,
    String _lastname,
    String _address,
    String _address2,
    String _city,
    String _state,
    String _zipcode)
{
    int rows;

    String query = String.Format(
        "INSERT INTO EmployeeInformation (firstname, middlename, lastname, address, address2, city, state, zipcode) values ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7});",
        _firstname, _middlename, _lastname, _address, _address2, _city, _state, _zipcode);

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionstring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: I'm not as experienced with SQL as I would like, but I believe when passing values to an insert, you can replace the indexes with `?`, like so: `"INSERT INTO EmployeeInformation (firstname, middlename, lastname, address, address2, city, state, zipcode) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);",
        _firstname, _middlename, _lastname, _address, _address2, _city, _state, _zipcode);`

Comment: @SeanPerkins replacing {x} with ? gave me `{"Incorrect syntax near '?'."}`, to the best of my knowledge {x} indexing is required by the `String.Format` object

Comment: **DON'T USE** `string.Format()` to build up your SQL statements - **DO USE** the parametrized version (with the `@_firstname`) **always** - this prevents you from being open to SQL injection attacks, it's better for performance, and it avoids lots of issues with having quotes or not and date formatting etc. - **ALWAYS** use parametrized queries - no exceptions!!

Comment: @marc_s thank you marc_s, im new to asp. i will move forward with the parameterized version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String values to be inserted in table should be in quotes. Second insert query created by string.format doesn't do that. First insert query is a parameterized one which is executed by sp_executesql procedure. No need of quotes there.

Comment: that did it, thank you sir. `...values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}')`